# How to configure Ubuntu Unity to have fixed workspace for external monitor

Tags: unity, workspaces, external-monitor

I am using Unity (ubuntu 13.04). Is there any way to make one of the workspace stay fixed for external monitor.

For example, I am in the middle of the presentation and I just want to quickly switch to another workspace,do somethings and come back to this workspace. This way, my audience, will not notice any interruptions (this is when they are taking notes, and I want to browse my emails).

I have seen my professor doing this on his Mac but I do not know how to do that on Ubuntu.